# How to badge file and folder using Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I want to badge a file and folder with some color (image). How can this be achieved?

I tried with icon service, and it works for files, but it is not working with folders.

I saw this behavior working [Dropbox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dropbox_%28service%29) (10.4, 10.5 and 10.6)- how can this be done?

The blog post *[Cocoa Tutorial: Custom Folder Icons](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/06/16/cocoa-tutorial-custom-folder-icons/)* was very close one for me, but it was not working as expected.

Is there another solution other than icon service?

Comment: I got the solution : Add a resource fork for the badging icon in a folder and load that as a badge for the folder icon.

Note: resource fork name should be end with '\r'

Comment: would you mind adding an answer and showing what you did?  I'd be interested to see.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dave DeLong Please find my solution give bellow , Pass folder Path you want to badge and NSData from badging icon.

The code will work only in intel if you want this be working in PPC replace the use 'NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding' with respect to PPC.

Hope you find this code useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following function is the solution I found for the problem

```
BOOL AddBadgeToItem(NSString* path,NSData* tag)

{   
    FSCatalogInfo info;
    FSRef par;
    FSRef ref;
    Boolean dir = false;

    if (tag&&(FSPathMakeRef([path fileSystemRepresentation],&par,&dir)==noErr)) 
    {
        HFSUniStr255 fork = {0,{0}};
        sint16 refnum = kResFileNotOpened;
        FSGetResourceForkName(&fork);

        if (dir) 
        {

            NSString *name = @"Icon\r";
            memset(&info,0,sizeof(info));
            ((FileInfo*)(&info.finderInfo))->finderFlags = kIsInvisible;

            OSErr error = FSCreateResourceFile(&par,[name lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding],(UniChar*)[name cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF16LittleEndianStringEncoding],kFSCatInfoFinderXInfo,&info,fork.length, fork.unicode,&ref,NULL);

            if( error == dupFNErr )
            {
                // file already exists; prepare to try to open it
                const char *iconFileSystemPath = [[path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"\000I\000c\000o\000n\000\r"] fileSystemRepresentation];

                OSStatus status = FSPathMakeRef((const UInt8 *)iconFileSystemPath, &ref, NULL);
                if (status != noErr)
                {
                    fprintf(stderr, "error: FSPathMakeRef() returned %d for file \"%s\"\n", (int)status, iconFileSystemPath);

                }
            }else if ( error != noErr)
            {
                return NO;
            }

        } 
        else 
        {
            BlockMoveData(&par,&ref,sizeof(FSRef));
            if (FSCreateResourceFork(&ref,fork.length,fork.unicode,0)!=noErr) 
            {
                //test

                if (FSOpenResourceFile(&ref,fork.length,fork.unicode,fsRdWrPerm,&refnum)!=noErr) {
                    return NO;
                }
                if (refnum!=kResFileNotOpened) {

                    UpdateResFile(refnum);
                    CloseResFile(refnum);

                    if (FSGetCatalogInfo(&par,kFSCatInfoFinderXInfo,&info,NULL,NULL,NULL)==noErr) {
                        ((ExtendedFileInfo*)(&info.extFinderInfo))->extendedFinderFlags = kExtendedFlagsAreInvalid;
                        FSSetCatalogInfo(&par,kFSCatInfoFinderXInfo,&info);
                    }
                }

                //Test end
                return NO;
            }
        }
        OSErr errorr = FSOpenResourceFile(&ref,fork.length,fork.unicode,fsRdWrPerm,&refnum);
        if (errorr!=noErr) {
            return NO;
        }
        if (refnum!=kResFileNotOpened) {
            CustomBadgeResource* cbr;

            int len = [tag length]; 
            Handle h = NewHandle(len);
            if (h) {
                BlockMoveData([tag bytes],*h,len);
                AddResource(h,kIconFamilyType,128,"\p");
                WriteResource(h);
                ReleaseResource(h);
            }

            h = NewHandle(sizeof(CustomBadgeResource)); 
            if (h) {
                cbr = (CustomBadgeResource*)*h;
                memset(cbr,0,sizeof(CustomBadgeResource));
                cbr->version = kCustomBadgeResourceVersion;
                cbr->customBadgeResourceID = 128;
                AddResource(h,kCustomBadgeResourceType,kCustomBadgeResourceID,"\p");
                WriteResource(h);
                ReleaseResource(h);
            }

            UpdateResFile(refnum);
            CloseResFile(refnum);

            if (FSGetCatalogInfo(&par,kFSCatInfoFinderXInfo,&info,NULL,NULL,NULL)==noErr) {
                ((ExtendedFileInfo*)(&info.extFinderInfo))->extendedFinderFlags = kExtendedFlagHasCustomBadge;
                FSSetCatalogInfo(&par,kFSCatInfoFinderXInfo,&info);
            }
        }
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: Hi Girish, I'm trying to badge folders in the finder with an accessory icon badge, but unsuccessfully so far. I tried this code but the result was a file named 'Icon' in the folder. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: @Joe Ricioppo : icon file resource fork created as part of badging folder.

Comment: @JoeRicioppo I am also facing the same issue . The code runs without any errors but nothing happens. How did you solve the problem???

Comment: still curious about it, do you guys had figured out that it works ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using the `-setIcon:forFile:options:` method on NSWorkspace, which lets you just specify an NSImage to apply to the file/folder at the path you give it.

Answer (score 0):

The intended approach is to create a [**Finder Sync** app extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html).