# modify file icon like dropbox in Mac

Tags: macos, dropbox

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to badge file and folder using cocoa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245021/how-to-badge-file-and-folder-using-cocoa)

in the dropbox folder, all file icons are added an circle on it, how to do this in Mac?Really want to know it, thank you!